# How do i Pass JSON Multiple parameters in JMeter with different users?

Tags: json, jmeter, parameter-passing

In my current scenario i need to login with multiple users into application and create articles using provided input formed in json which have more than 50 parameters.How can i do that need to prepare two csv files or what,pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would come up with:

1. A single JSON file containing placeholders for [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which you will be using for parameterization like:

   ```
   {
     "firstName": "${firstName}",
     "lastName": "${lastName}",
     "phone": ${phone},
     etc.
   }
   ```
2. Then I would create a CSV file containing the parameterization information like:

   ```
   firstName,lastName,phone
   John,Doe,123456789
   Jane,Doe,987654321
   etc.
   ```
3. Configure JMeter to read the data from CSV using the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
4. Reference the file from point 1 in the "Body Data" section of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler using [__eval() and __FileToString() functions combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/):

   ```
   ${__eval(${__FileToString(data.json,,)})}
   ```

   [image]